How to check if there is non-zero number in part of the string with regex?
I have a string which has to look like this:

XXXXX-YYYYYYYY-ZZZ
XXXXX-YYYYYYY-ZZZ
XXXXX-YYYYYY-ZZZ
XXXXX-YYYYY-ZZZ
XXXXX-YYYY-ZZZ
XXXXX-YYY-ZZZ
XXXXX-YY-ZZZ
XXXXX-Y-ZZZ
XXXXXYYYYYYYYZZZ
XXXXXYYYYYYYZZZ
XXXXXYYYYYYZZZ
XXXXXYYYYYZZZ
XXXXXYYYYZZZ
XXXXXYYYZZZ
XXXXXYYZZZ
XXXXXYZZZ

Regex for each part is:

X: ^[23][0-9]{4}$.
Y: ^(?=.*[1-9])[0-9]{1,8}$.
Z: ^[0-9]{3}$.

As for dashes, it has to be either both or none (it can't be only one, e.g. 22345-12987 or 2234512-987)
Examples of such strings are:

29803-134-000
31234-000134-151
31234000134151

It can't be e.g. 22345-00-987 <- Those zeroes as YY are not correct.
I don't know how to write a full regular expression. Please, help.
Thanks.
I tried (^[23][0-9]{4}\-(?=.*[1-9])[0-9]{1,8}\-[0-9]{3}$)|(^[23][0-9]{4}(?=.*[1-9])[0-9]{1,8}[0-9]{3}$), but that allows 12345-00-987 / 1234500987.

Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts. Please do share more samples with digits in code tags in your question to make it more clear, thank you, cheers.

Your regex matches neither 12345-00-987 nor 1234500987, since they both start with the digit 1. Anyway, I think you can fix it by just replacing .* with \d* , because you don't want . to also match hyphens.

The problem is, the positive lookahead is seached for in the entire string, and thus it finds a valid number in the Z part.

@logi-kal While you are correct with pointing out bad examples, using .* or \d* in the lookahead is rather irrelevant because if there is anything other than digits or dashes in the string, the regex won't match anyways ...

@derpirscher By construction there can't be anything other than digits or dashes. Anyway, I partially correct myself: the second lookahead should be (?=[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]{3}) in order to ensure that [1-9] character is matched by the Y-regex.

Aside: There's no need to escape -. The only place where it has special meaning is inside [].

Do you really have to do this with a single regexp? It would be easier to use a simple pattern to extract the whole string, then use code to split it into 3 parts, and check that they follow the required patterns for each.

IMO It's easier to describe what you want to avoid in a negative lookahead:
^[23][0-9]{4}(-?)(?!0*\1[0-9]{3}$)[0-9]{1,8}\1[0-9]{3}$

The negative lookahead (?!0*\1[0-9]{3}$) describes the substring from the second part (full of zeroes) until the end.
demo
Note also the use of a capture group and a back-reference to ensure that the string has two or zero hyphens. (Feel free to rewrite the pattern with an alternation if you prefer).

Thank you very much! I understand your answer and that is a good approach. Cheers!
